How to disable non-intended user input in the terminal C#
When i write a infinite loop that doesn't have any behaviour on its body, the user still have the possibility to write text at it, even without calling any input function:
Note: I'm using Linux, Manjaro. .NET 8; Shell: zsh
using System;

namespace Program;

public class UserInputTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // user input is not disabled
        while (true) {}
    }
}

If i start to type on my keyboard some letters, they will be visible in the terminal. How can i disable that behaviour?
(Note: I know that a infinite loop isn't useful, but it's only an example of my problem.)
I already tried to close the input or output streams, but it not worked:
Console.In.Close();
Console.Out.Close();

Console.OpenStandardInput().Close();
Console.OpenStandardOutput().Close();


Can't reproduce with VS 2022, .Net 8, and while (true) { } or await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));.

It depends on the exact terminal you're using. For example, Windows' command prompt will keep track of the characters typed, but not draw them to the screen until read by the program or the program is closed.

I fixed it by launching a process with the Linux command stty [echo | -echo] (echo to enable, -echo to disable). It enables/disables the echoing of the character inputed by the user.
ProcessStartInfo info = new("/bin/bash")
{
    Arguments = $"-c \"stty -echo\"",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

Process process = new()
{
    StartInfo = info
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

